# How do you "Build" an exe that includes all the resource files like pics? Can exe be put on a web page?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have students in high school who have created some programs using Visual Studio C#. They created some games and would like to now upload them to the web. I am pretty new to Visual Studio C#. I thought after a program was "built" that you could go into the bin/debug folder and get the exe file for the program and be able to play the game without having to have Visual Studio on the actual computer you are playing it on. It works with some of their games but some of them, there are graphical files that are missing in the exe file if all the other files aren't stored in the same place. How can I get a clean exe of their game? Can that exe be loaded up onto a web server so they can play it from there or at least download it from there?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft wrote a guide on how to do exactly this. It's on their **MSDN** website, which is sort of like the developer back-bone for a lot of Microsoft software and documentation.

Old guide: [Adding and Editing Resources (Visual C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k989cfy%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Newer guide: [How to: Add or Remove Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3bka19x4(v=vs.100).aspx)

The gist is that the program needs to know where the files are, relative to the location of the compiled binary (in this case, an `.EXE`); There's several different ways to do this, depending on your level of expertise. I would suggest that you take a look at the guides above to start that journey.

Comment: Thanks for this information! This website will be a great resource for my classes, thanks for the help!

Comment: No problem, @LindaBrown -- please mark this as the selected answer if you believe it qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

there's a few ways of doing this.  (Also, make sure you're creating a 'release' build when you compile).

You can include resources in your game by creating a resources file.  This is something I usually do only on winforms applications etc.

If you have on-disk files you need to distribute those on-disk files along side your game.  You could do this by zipping up your game.exe and the /files/images.img folder (or what ever your resources content folder is named).

If you're feeling adventurous you could create a 'deployment project' which is a project that allows you to create an installer file.  This is a bit more work however you will have fine grained control over what files go where etc.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

EXE files generally aren't self contained for video games with many resources, just add resources in an external folder and make sure the paths to the resources in their games are not absolute but relative in the local directory.

So for example:
get rid of paths like `C:/Users/Bob/Desktop/Game/Images/player.png` and replace with `/Images/Player.png`.

Also, an EXE generally doesn't run client side on webpages, it is possible but difficult. Things such as Flash are made for this sort of issue. I'd say make the webpage a place where they can download their games. Github has a nice way to do free websites called gh-pages. OFC, you could host one yourself but that would require a lot of setup work.

Like Monza said, you can zip up the files for download. Or, you could create an installer if you wanted to be really ambitious.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought after a program was "built" that you could go into the bin/debug folder and get the exe file for the program and be able to play the game without having to have Visual Studio on the actual computer you are playing it on.

That is correct, given that the other machine has the necessary .NET framework version installed AND any other resources like .dll files and config files are also present.   When the application is ready for release, you can set the Build options in the project properties to Release, and then when you build all the files needed for distribution will be in the bin\Release folder.

> It works with some of their games but some of them, there are graphical files that are missing in the exe file if all the other files aren't stored in the same place.

This may depend on how the application was written.  If resources like pictures are [embedded in the assembly](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/319292) then those files will not be needed to run on another machine.  If the application is using hard coded paths for the image resources in the source code, then the application will likely break if the necessary files aren't present when the .exe is executed.

> Can that exe be loaded up onto a web server so they can play it from there or at least download it from there?

Yes - you could upload the .exe to a file server to make available for a download, but you would not be able to run it within a browser over the web.  I would recommend zipping up the .exe and other files needed and hosting the .zip file on the web server for download; browsers may give a warning or block downloading an .exe .

Hope this explains it a little bit for you.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense. Thank you so much for taking the time to explain so much. I sure appreciate it and I know the students will too :-)